# Why does React say not to set 'selected' property on <option> elements?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

[edit] This was due to my own confusion, apologies.

Setting the `selected` property on `<option>` elements in JSX works perfectly, but it causes React the throw a warning:

`Warning: Use the 'defaultValue' or 'value' props on <select> instead of setting 'selected' on <option>.`

Setting `defaultValue` on the parent `<select>` element causes the `value` of the `<select>` to default to that setting, but it does not set the default selected `<option>`. So this throws what the user sees and what is actually selected out of sync.

Setting the `value` property on the parent `<select>` element forces me to then add an onChange handler, set the value in component state, and write a bunch of extra code all to accomplish what simply setting `selected` on the `<option>` elements does with a single word.

Does anybody know why React throws this warning? I don't want to write a bunch of additional code to remove a warning that doesn't seem to map to reality. It works fine as far as I can tell, so why shouldn't I use it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that `defaultValue` doesn't "set the default selected `<option>`" it seems to for me?

Comment: `<select defaultValue={"B"}>
    <option>{"A"}</option>
    <option>{"B"}</option>
    <option>{"C"}</option>
</select>`

In that code sample, when the component first renders the value of the select element is "B", but what the user sees as the "default selected" is A, as it would be if I had no defaultValue prop set.

Comment: Huh? That's not what happens though.. https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/39163/

Comment: Yeah you're right, sorry. I plead temporary insanity. I was trying to match the defaultValue to the content of the option instead of the value of the option (which in my use case are different). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @rodwa4: *"I was trying to match the defaultValue to the content of the option instead of the value of the option (which in my use case are different)"* Well, that's not how `select` elements work. The value is the *value*, not the text, where they differ.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the React documentation to go along with that warning:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

If you do it the way they're suggesting, you could render your `<SELECT>` component with a "value" property. Then you would need to write a handler function for the onChange event, to make sure that the component re-renders to reflect the user's changed selection.

If you tried to manage this flow of information at the level of the individual `<OPTION>` element, I think you'd have the same challenges, and then some. For example, let's say option A is selected on page load. Then the user selects option B. Option B would need to re-render to appear selected, and option A would need to re-render to appear unselected. For the onClick event on option B to trigger a change on option A, the information would have to be passed from option B to the parent Select element, and then down to the option A element.

That React documentation also talks about an "uncontrolled" `<SELECT>` element, which I think means that it would render once initially (and you could specify a defaultValue for it, but React wouldn't keep re-rendering it in realtime.

Comment: Hmm, I think I understand what you're saying, but it doesn't seem to align with what actually happens. Here is my code:

`<select>
    <option key={1}>Option A</option>
    <option key={2} selected>Option B</option>
    <option key={3}>Option C</option>
</select>`

That code does not behave how you are describing at all. It initially renders with a value of 'Option B' and 'Option B' selected. When the user clicks and selects 'Option C' or 'Option A', the respective selected option is now both selected and the option. It just works simply with no extra legwork needed.